# Why is request_async significantly slower then aiohttp in aws lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-requests, aiohttp

I'm refactoring the following functions to use `requests_async` instead of `aiohttp`

Original code:

```
async def ping_url(session, url):
    logger.debug('Ping: %s', url)
    try:
        response = await session.get(url)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        logger.info('Ping timeout for %s', url)
        return ('TIMEOUT', url)
    else:
        logger.debug('Ping done for %s', url)
        return (response.status, url)


async def ping_urls(urls, headers=None):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout, headers=headers) as session:
        tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(
                ping_url(session, url)
            ) for url in urls
        ]
        ping_results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return ping_results
```

After refactoring:

```
async def ping_url(session, url):
    logger.debug('Ping: %s', url)
    try:
        response = await session.get(url)
    except requests_async.exceptions.Timeout:
        logger.info('Ping timeout for %s', url)
        return ('TIMEOUT', url)
    else:
        logger.debug('Ping done for %s', url)
        return (response.status_code, url)


async def ping_urls(urls, headers=None):
    async with requests_async.Session() as session:
        session.headers.update(headers or {})
        session.timeout = 2
        tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(
                ping_url(session, url)
            ) for url in urls
        ]
        ping_results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return ping_results
```

If I run the `ping_urls` coro on my machine with the same URL pinged by my lambda, there is no significant difference in performance between the two versions.

Inside my AWS lambda, the response version is 3 times slower than the `aiohttp` version.

Any idea on what could be the cause of the difference and why it affects the code only when it's executed in the aws lambda?

I've been checking that the version of dependencies installed by my packaging scripts are the same as the one I use locally.

I have also edited my lambda to execute both versions sequentially in the same invocation to ensure that the execution context is the same, but the performance differences are the same (3/1).

Comment: See what happens if you increase the memory allocated to the Lambda function.  If things speed up, the library is CPU bound.  Lambda function invocations have approximately the equivalent of *m × (8 ÷ 30) × 2.6* GHz of CPU cycles available, where m is the amount of memory in GB allocated to the function.

Comment: going from 128 to 1280 mb of ram things speedup quite a lot, but the ratio remain similar eg: 0.062 vs 0.015 instead of 0.62 vs 0.15
Further increases in the memory do not causes improvements.
Not quite sure on how to interpret this observation.
It could be that the networking factor is way more significant when I compare the two versions locally and that being lambda executed closer to the instances I'm pinging the limiting factor became the cpu.
this however does not explain why further increasing the ram end consequently the cpu the execution speed remain constant for both versions.

Comment: When further increases don't improve performance, that suggests you're no longer CPU bound.

Comment: yes but at that point I would expect the network factor to kick in and see the execution time to converge for the two versions. this is not what I'm witnessing.
after a certain point the execution time remain constant for both versions but not at the same value.
request version stays at around 0.06s and the other at 0.015s this is the part I struggle to explain